# How to create a namespace and export a function into it?

Tags: r

Is there a way to declare a namespace and export a function into it so that it can be accessed using `::`, without creating a whole package?

The following works for `:::` but not `::`:

```
ns <- namespace::makeNamespace("my_namespace")
assign("test",7, env=ns)
my_namespace:::test # Triple colon - works.
# [1] 7
my_namespace::test # Double colon - doesn't work.
# Error: 'test' is not an exported object from 'namespace:my_namespace'
```

Is there an alternative to `assign` that would make the last line work? (The goal is to be able to simulate a package while developing it, so other files can use it as if it is a complete package but it can be quickly reloaded using `source` rather than `devtools::install`.)

Comment: Please indicate whether you are using non base packages. Can't find the `makeNamespace` function.

Comment: @nicola Apologies - it is namespace::makeNamespace. I have edited the question.

Comment: This package doesn't even exist anymore... (2024)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`base::namespaceExport(ns, ls(ns))` seems to work (of course you can also use a subset as the list of objects to export in the second argument). Use it once you have defined all the objects in the namespace that you wish to export:

```
ns <- namespace::makeNamespace("my_namespace")
assign("test", 7, env = ns)
base::namespaceExport(ns, ls(ns))

my_namespace::test
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: I get the error: `Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘namespace’`.
From the line: `ns <- namespace::makeNamespace("my_namespace")`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same use case, and designed this :

```
#' simulate a package
#'
#' simulate loading a namespace or attaching a package. designed to make reprexes easy. The input function's closer env is set to
#' the namespace and no fancy feature such as registering S3 methods is supported
#'
#' @param name string, name of fake package
#' @param exported named list of exported functions
#' @param unexported named list of unexported functions
#' @param attach whether to attach the fake package
#'
#' @noRd
fake_package <- function(name, exported = NULL, unexported = NULL, attach = TRUE) {
  # create an empty namespace
  ns <- namespace::makeNamespace(name)
  # makethis namespace the closure env of our input functions
  exported <- lapply(exported, `environment<-`, ns)
  unexported <- lapply(unexported, `environment<-`, ns)
  # place these in the namespace
  list2env(exported, ns)
  list2env(unexported, ns)
  # export relevant functions
  namespaceExport(ns, names(exported))
  if(attach) {
    # copy exported funs to "package:pkg" envir of the search path
    attach(exported, name = paste0("package:", name))
  }
  invisible()
}
```

Here's how to use it (here we leave `attach` to the default `TRUE` so we create a `"package:fake"` environment on the search path) :

```
fake_package(
  "fake",
  exported = list(add_2 = function(x) add_1(x) + 1),
  unexported = list(add_1 = function(x) x + 1))

# the search path looks as it would after a library call
search()
#>  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:fake"      "package:stats"    
#>  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
#>  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
#> [10] "tools:callr"       "package:base"

# add_2 was exported
add_2
#> function(x) add_1(x) + 1
#> <environment: namespace:fake>

fake::add_2
#> function(x) add_1(x) + 1
#> <environment: namespace:fake>

fake:::add_2
#> function(x) add_1(x) + 1
#> <environment: namespace:fake>

# add_1 was not, so as expected can't be found
add_1
#> Error: object 'add_1' not found

fake::add_1
#> Error: 'add_1' is not an exported object from 'namespace:fake'

fake:::add_1
#> function(x) x + 1
#> <environment: namespace:fake>

# let's try it
add_2(3)
#> [1] 5
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, albeit the `makeNamespace` has changed position in body of `loadNamespace`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought the function would be stable enough to spare a dependency but it was poor judgement, let's just make it depend on the {namespace} package.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following helpful for your intended use case of speeding up package development:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/getFromNamespace.html

> Description
>
> Utility functions to access and replace the non-exported functions in a namespace, for use in developing packages with namespaces.